# What does mongodb is not a function mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm new to programming, I'm trying to follow a web developemnt course when connecting to database I created I get the error "mongodb.connect is not a function".

I try to connect to the database using the following code.

```
        let mongodb = require('mongodb');
        let db
        let connectionString = '';
        mongodb.connect(connectionString,{useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: 
        true},function(err, client){
        db = client.db();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to the database from the client (which uses MongoClient from the library).

```js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

let db;

const connectionString = 'mongodb://' // Change this to your uri
const client = new MongoClient(connectionString)
```

Then you can connect

```js
await client.connect();
db = client.db();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

let databaseName = '';
let connectionString = '';

MongoClient.connect(connectionString, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, (error, client) => {
  if (error) 
    return console.log("Connection failed for some reason");

  const db = client.db(databaseName);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this one

```
let mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
```

this could be for the version of mongodb you are using instead of version used in the course.